# my button update image doesn't show the modal despite it is working in update profile

Tags: javascript, html, angular, button, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 modals one to update name and bio and the other is to update  the  image. The first one  is  working and it's showing the modal and the  second is not here the code of html, the first modal is with `id=exampleModal` and the second one (which is not working) is with the `id=exampleModal2`.

```
<br>
<br>
{{Uid}}
<div class="container">
  <article class="uk-comment">
    <header class="uk-comment-header">
      <div class="uk-grid-medium uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
        <div class="uk-width-auto">
          <img class="uk-comment-avatar" [src]="dataProfile.image" width="200" height="200" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="uk-width-expand">
          <h4 class="uk-comment-title uk-margin-remove"><a class="uk-link-reset" href="/profi">{{dataProfile.firstName}}</a>
          </h4>
          <button class="btn btn-info" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">update</button>
          <button class="btn btn-info" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal2">update image</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="uk-comment-body">
      <p>{{dataProfile.bio}}</p>
    </div>

  </article>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="dataProfile.firstName" >
          <input type="text" name="bio" [(ngModel)]="dataProfile.bio">
          <p class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="successUpdate">{{successUpdate}}</p>
          <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="update()">update now</button>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
             <input type="file" accept=".jpg , .png" (change)="uploadImage($event)">
              <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="updateImage()">update now </button>
            </form>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. Your both modal is missing `</div></div>` closing div tags at the end.